# copy files from mac to ubuntu phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I want to transfer (copy) files from my macbook air to my ubuntu phone; especially music files from iTunes.

I tried to connect my ubuntu phone (Aquaris E5 ubuntu edition) to my macbook air and it doesn't seem to recognize it.

Can anyone help to to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Android Transfer](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/) to transfer file from any ubuntu or android device.

Comment: Thank you! It works. Is it correct that for copying files from ubuntu to macbook you use WiFitransfer?

Comment: yes,you can also use that,though i have never tried it my self.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable ssh on Ubuntu device, you can handle with files in both directions via scp command.

Comment: I suggest expanding this answer with details on how to enable sshd on an Ubuntu touch device (and then how to access that device).